# Issues with ungreedy match

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I'm matching the text here http://pastebin.com/PfjEgQpd with the following regex:

```
preg_match('#(.*(?s))(particella |particelle |p\.|part\.|p |part |mappale |mapp\.|mapp |n\.|\*) *(\d+[\d /\p{Pd}]*)($|.{0,20}(?s)(graffati|particella |particelle |p\.|.*part\.|p |part |mappale |mapp\.|mapp |n\.|subalterno |subalterni |sub\.|s\.|sub |s |\bcat\b|\bcategoria\b|\brendita\b|\bvani\b|\bconsistenza\b|\bR\.C\.\b))#i', $txt, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)
```

with `$offset = 944` and I'm getting the following output in `$matches`.

I expected to match the `1184` but it matches the `4` instead.
I tried with `(?sU)` too with no luck.

```
$matches = array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(59) "* 1184 sub.702, vioolo San Vincenzo n.4, piano T, Categoria"
    [1]=>
    int(1226)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(36) "* 1184 sub.702, vioolo San Vincenzo "
    [1]=>
    int(1226)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "n."
    [1]=>
    int(1262)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    int(1264)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) ", piano T, Categoria"
    [1]=>
    int(1265)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Categoria"
    [1]=>
    int(1276)
  }
}
$offset = int(944)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: the point is that there are greedy subpatterns in the pattern: `.*` and `{0,20}`. They should be turned into *lazy* subpatterns since otherwise, your captured texts will only hold 1 symbol (left greedy subpattern "gobbles" as much as it can and does not let the group next to it capture more than 1 symbol since they require at least one symbol).

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/D2YHXb), use

```
$re = '~(.*?(?s))(particella |particelle |p\.|part\.|p |part |mappale |mapp\.|mapp |n\.|\*) *(\d+[\d /\p{Pd}]*)($|.{0,20}?(?s)(graffati|particella |particelle |p\\.|.*part\\.|p |part |mappale |mapp\.|mapp |n\.|subalterno |subalterni |sub\.|s\.|sub |s |\bcat\b|\bcategoria\b|\brendita\b|\bvani\b|\bconsistenza\b|\bR\.C\.\b))~';
```

Since your pattern is too fragile I optimized it a bit and replace   with `\s` everywhere since your intent is to match all whitespace in those places:

```
(?s)(.*?)(particell[ea]\s+|p(?:art)?[.\s]+|mapp(?:(?:ale)?\s+|\.)|n\.|\*)\s*(\d+[\d\s/\p{Pd}]*)($|.{0,20}?(graffati|particell[ae]\s+|p(?:art)?[.\s]+|mapp(?:(?:ale)?\s+|\.)|n\.|subaltern[oi]\s+|s(?:ub)?[.\s]+|\bcat(?:egoria)?\b|\brendita\b|\bvani\b|\bconsistenza\b|\bR\.C\.\b))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iX4bA3/2) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/K4bAgw).

Comment: What is the offset? BTW, your pattern is very fragile and may cause catastrophical backtracking. To fix it, I'd need to know whta exactly do you try to extract with it.

Comment: I have the same problem here http://siba.thenetworksolution.it/allegati/H3018500D7FDDE9ACA05671F49F4F3746A69DAF96.1329514.pdf.txt
The same regex with offset = 1155 matches '57/1998' instead of '454'. Lazy subpatterns won't help in this case. I'm trying to extract cadastral data "foglio 1, particella 454, sub.4 e sub.5.". This is the regex that should match the "particella": 454. The offset I provided is the offset of the "foglio 1" (previously matched in my code with another regex).

Comment: I have checked and it seems your regex also matched [`57/1998`](https://ideone.com/rvLGFE).

Comment: But I want to match the `454` first.

Comment: I think you can use `(?s)(.*?)(particell[ea]\s+|p(?:art)?[.\s]|mapp(?:(?:ale)?\s|\.)|n\.|\*)\s*(\d+[\d\s/\p{Pd}]*)($|.{0,20}?(graffati|particell[ae]\s|p(?:art)?[.\s]|mapp(?:(?:ale)?\s|\.)|n\.|subaltern[oi]\s|s(?:ub)?[.\s]|\bcat(?:egoria)?\b|\brendita\b|\bvani\b|\bconsistenza\b|\bR\.C\.\b))`. I [optimized the pattern](https://ideone.com/K4bAgw) and replace regular spaces with `\s` pattern that matches all whitespace characters. If you add `/u` modifier at the end, you will also match all Unicode whitespaces and digits with it.

Comment: It's not that simple. These kind of data may be specified in many ways in such documents, and I'm parsing in batch many files. There is many logic before and after the regular expressions. Except for the greedy matching of *, it is almost perfect.

Comment: After some tests on regex101.com I discovered the issue is the carriage return between the prefix `particella` and `454`, but I expected the `\s` to match line feeds.

How I can correct the greediness so the regex will match the `454`?

Comment: `\s` matches carriage returns. Just use `\s+`.

Comment: I used \s*. Btw I solved the issue just now. The problem was the space after `particella` in the second group.

Comment: I added `+` quantifiers to my suggested pattern.